# How do i add a fixed text beside bar chart using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add a text beside a Bar chart . it will be look like 
two bar chart both of them will have a text in their right side. I tried in many ways but couldn't find or may i didn't understand because i am beginners in D3 . This is my first question in stackoverflow .

I wrote this

```js
var w = 500;
   var h = 100;
   var barPadding = 5;
   
   var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
       11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];
   
   //Create SVG element Men 2010
   var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

   svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / dataset.length);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - (d * 4);}
      )
     .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d*4;  //Just the data value
     })
   .attr("fill", function(d) {
       return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
    });

///for the fixed text
var svgContainertext = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 100)
                                     .attr("height", 20);
                          
svgContainertext.append("g")
.selectAll("text")
.append("text")

.text("2010")
.attr("x",20)
.attr("y",10)
.attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "black");
```

But the code is not showing the result. I am new to D3 . 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is not showing because you ad the text after .selectAll("text"), which results in an empty selection, hence nowhere to add your text.

Furthermore, the text you are adding is in a new svg, and is not linked anyhow to your chart. I created a plunk to show how to put the text in the same svg: http://plnkr.co/edit/EHVB65sn7Oc67s7woKrj?p=preview

Updated code:

```
var w = 500;
var h = 100;
var barPadding = 5;
var textWidth = 30;
var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
  11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25
];

 //Create SVG element Men 2010
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * ((w - textWidth) / dataset.length);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 4);
  })
  .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 4; //Just the data value
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
  });

 ///for the fixed text


svg.append("g")
  .append("text")
  .text("2010")
  .attr("x", w - textWidth)
  .attr("y", h / 2)
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "11px")
  .attr("fill", "black");
```

What I did is use the same svg to append the text (in a group). I also reduced the space available for the bar chart using a textWidth variable, allowing to view the text and position it properly.

Comment: You're welcome :-). do not hesitate to mark one of the answer as answer and upvote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Removing `.selectAll("text")` will show the text 2010. I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snrm4duy/) to show this.

If you want to read about selections, I suggest you have a read of [this article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)

basically it is not working because the `.selectAll('text')` returns an empty selection and after that you append a text node to nothing.

It works for the `rects` drawn earlier because the `.data()` method is used on that selection.

```
var svgContainertext = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 20);

svgContainertext.append("g")
  .append("text")
  .text("2010")
  .attr("x",20)
  .attr("y",10)
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "11px")
  .attr("fill", "black");
```

Comment: It works too . Thanks a lot @Benjamin Udink ten Cate :).